# Problem loading login page Reactjs - Keycloak - Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, spring-cloud-gateway

Hello this is my first post so apologies for any mistakes being made.. :)

I have been trying to integrate React with Keycloak & Spring Cloud Gateway trying to access another Spring Boot microservice.

My problem is that Chrome keeps making an infinite loop when hitting http://localhost:3000 where my React server is up and running

At least when using Edge it prints the error in the picture but no infinite loop like Chrome does; Microsoft Edge error below:

[image: Microsoft Edge error]

Before posting any code I would like to ask if there is somewhere I can find an example of integrating these technologies together.

For Keycloak I am using `<ReactKeycloakProvider>` which I get it from `"@react-keycloak/web": "^3.4.0"`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use the Keycloak login page
here's the service :

```
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(String username, String password) {

        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(authURL);
        post.setHeader("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
        List<BasicNameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", grantType));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", clientId));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(post);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        BufferedReader rd = null;
        try {
            rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line1 = "";
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (!((line1 = rd.readLine()) != null))
                    break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ResponseEntity.ok(line1);
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
    }
```

controller ::

```
@PostMapping("/api/public/auth/login")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@RequestBody LoginRequest request) {
    return authService.authenticateUser(request.email, request.password);
}
```

then look for how to store token in localstorage midlleware ....